# Why isn't the pointer last changing in the main function when I assigned to it the next Card?

Tags: c, pointers

```
void insertEndC(card* last, int val) {
    card* newCard;
    newCard = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
    newCard->val = val;
    if (last != NULL) {
        last->nextCard = newCard;
        newCard->prevCard = last;
        last = last->nextCard;
    }
    else {
        last = newCard;
        last->prevCard = NULL;
    }   
    last->nextCard = NULL;
}
```

does the pointer change only over the scope of this procedure?

Comment: C is pass by value. The code shown only changes the *local **copy*** of the value which had been passed to `last` by the caller.

Answer (score 4):

"does the pointer change only over the scope of this procedure?"

Correct, any updates to the address that `last` points to will not persist outside of the scope of `insertEndC()`.  You need  to pass in the address of the pointer in order to change where `last` points:

```
void insertEndC(card** last,int val) {
```

And of course change the rest of the function code to de-reference `last`.

Comment: Also, change the function call to pass address of pointer.
Eg. If your function call was `insertEndC(head, 4);` , make it `insertEndC(&head, 4);`
    
Or use `void insertEndC(card *& last, int val) {...}`
This way, no need to change the function call

Answer (score 3):

Your **last** in function **insertEndC()** is just a local variable which is totally different from the origin pointer in function **main()**. They are store in different memory locations.

If you want to change the value of a pointer, its address is needed. Then you can overwrite the value in correct address, not in the address of local variable.

Example:

```
void reset_char_pointer(char **addr_of_pointer)
{
    // Create new char *
    char *new_pointer;
    new_pointer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(16));
    strcpy(new_pointer, "hello world!");

    // Overwrite the char * value in addr_of_pointer
    *addr_of_pointer = new_pointer;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    char *target;
    reset_char_pointer(&target);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

So, in your case, you have to pass the address of last to insertEndC(), then change the value of last.

Your function should look like:

```
void insertEndC(card **addr_of_last, int val)
{
    card *new_last;

    // ...

    *addr_of_last = new_last;
}
```